# Error de sintaxis al cargar datos

Tags: php, mysql

Consulta Estoy intentando cargar los datos de la base de datos, para cargarlos en una tabla y me muestra un error de sintaxis en el network.

```
function historico(){
    global $mysqli;
    $where = "";
    $where2 = "";
    $draw = $_REQUEST["draw"];
    $idtarea            = (!empty($_REQUEST['idtarea']) ? $_REQUEST['idtarea'] : '');
    $idproyecto     = (!empty($_REQUEST['idproyecto']) ? $_REQUEST['idproyecto'] : '');
    $idsubproyecto  = (!empty($_REQUEST['idsubproyecto']) ? $_REQUEST['idsubproyecto'] : '');
    $start   = (!empty($_REQUEST['start']) ? $_REQUEST['start'] : 0);   
    $length   = (!empty($_REQUEST['length']) ? $_REQUEST['length'] : 10);
    $orderByColumnIndex  = $_REQUEST['order'][0]['0'];
    $orderBy = 0;
    $orderType = "DESC";
    $resultado      = '';

    $query  = "SELECT a.idusuario as idusuario,b.usuario as usuario, a.fecha as fecha FROM historicoactividades a inner join usuarios b on a.idusuario = b.id WHERE idtarea = $idtarea AND idgantt = $idsubproyecto AND idganttpadre = $idproyecto";    
    $hayFiltros = 0;
    for($i=0 ; $i<count($_REQUEST['columns']);$i++){
        $column = $_REQUEST['columns'][$i]['data'];//we get the name of each column using its index from POST request
        if ($_REQUEST['columns'][$i]['search']['value']!="") {
            $campo = $_REQUEST['columns'][$i]['search']['value'];
            $campo = str_replace('^','',$campo);
            $campo = str_replace('$','',$campo);

            if ($column == 'usuario') {
                $column = 'b.usuario';
                $where[]=" $column = '".$campo."' ";
            }
            if ($column == 'fecha') {
                $column = 'a.fecha';
                $where[]=" $column like '%".$campo."%' ";
            }   
            $hayFiltros++;
        }
    }
    // echo $hayFiltros;
    if ($hayFiltros > 0)
        $where = " AND ".implode(" AND " , $where)." ";
    else
        $where = "";

    $query  .= " $where $where2";
    if(!$result = $mysqli->query($query)){
      die($mysqli->error);  
    }
```

este es el error que se me muestra en el sql   este es el error que me muestra en el sql #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'AND

Comment: Prueba realizar un echo de `$query` y a lo mejor notas algo raro en la consulta.

Comment: Necesitas validar las variables que estás recibiendo, probablemente alguna que usas en el filtro está vacía, como `$idtarea` que asignas cadena vacía si no aparece en `$_REQUEST`. En todo caso, arma la consulta de acuerdo a los valores recibidos, si alguno de los campos está vacío, no lo incluyas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega los filtros en un array y, al final, se unen a la consulta con implode(). Toma nota de los comentarios en las modificaciones que hice a tu código:

```
function historico(){
    global $mysqli;
    $where = "";
    $where2 = "";
    $draw = $_REQUEST["draw"];
    $idtarea = (!empty($_REQUEST['idtarea']) ? $_REQUEST['idtarea'] : '');
    $idproyecto = (!empty($_REQUEST['idproyecto']) ? $_REQUEST['idproyecto'] : '');
    $idsubproyecto = (!empty($_REQUEST['idsubproyecto']) ? $_REQUEST['idsubproyecto'] : '');
    $start = (!empty($_REQUEST['start']) ? $_REQUEST['start'] : 0);   
    $length = (!empty($_REQUEST['length']) ? $_REQUEST['length'] : 10);
    $orderByColumnIndex  = $_REQUEST['order'][0]['0'];
    $orderBy = 0;
    $orderType = "DESC";
    $resultado = '';

    // Crea un array para armar los filtros
    $filtros = [];
    if(!empty($idtarea)) {
        // Puse cada valor entre comillas porque el valor por default es cadena
        // En caso de que el tipo de dato sea numérico no debería haber problema
        $filtros[] = "idtarea = '$idtarea'";
    }
    if(!empty($idsubproyecto)) {
        $filtros[] = "idtgantt = '$idsubproyecto'";
    }
    if(!empty($idproyecto)) {
        $filtros[] = "idtganttpadre = '$idproyecto'";
    }

    for($i=0 ; $i<count($_REQUEST['columns']);$i++){
        $column = $_REQUEST['columns'][$i]['data'];//we get the name of each column using its index from POST request
        if ($_REQUEST['columns'][$i]['search']['value']!="") {
            $campo = $_REQUEST['columns'][$i]['search']['value'];
            $campo = str_replace('^','',$campo);
            $campo = str_replace('$','',$campo);

            if ($column == 'usuario') {
                $column = 'b.usuario';
                $filtros[] = "$column = '$campo'";
            }
            if ($column == 'fecha') {
                $column = 'a.fecha';
        // Si el tipo de campo es cadena no hay problema con esto
        // Pero si es DATE o DATETIME no puedes usar like, te va a dar error
                $filtros[] = "$column like '%$campo%'";
            }   
        }
    }

    $filtro = '';
    if(count($filtros) == 0) {
        // Aquí deberías tomar alguna acción, como mensaje de error o cambiar la forma en que se hace la consulta
    } else {
        $filtro = ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $filtros);
    }
    $query  = "SELECT a.idusuario as idusuario,b.usuario as usuario, a.fecha as fecha FROM historicoactividades a inner join usuarios b on a.idusuario = b.id $filtro";    

    if(!$result = $mysqli->query($query)){
      die($mysqli->error);  
    }
}
```